# Is there a way to change the datetime format in fullcalender version 5.9.0 on eventdrop

Tags: javascript, datetime, fullcalendar

The ajax request is sending date and time in the following format

```
id  "41"
start   "Mon+Oct+04+2021+17:10:00+GMT+0300+(East+Africa+Time)+17:10:0"
end "Mon+Oct+04+2021+18:40:00+GMT+0300+(East+Africa+Time)+18:40:0"
```

Is there a way to change it to meet the following format

```
 id "41"
    start   "2021-10-04 17:10:0"
    end "202110-04 18:40:0"
```

My code at eventdrop look like this

```
 eventDrop: function(arg) {
            var start = arg.event.start+' '+arg.event.start.getHours()+':'+arg.event.start.getMinutes()+':'+arg.event.start.getSeconds();
            if (arg.event.end == null) {
                end = start;
            } else {
                var end = arg.event.end+' '+arg.event.end.getHours()+':'+arg.event.end.getMinutes()+':'+arg.event.end.getSeconds();
            }
            $.ajax({
              url: 'process/edit.php',
              type:"POST",
              data:{id:arg.event.id, start:start, end:end},
            });
        }
```

Any suggestion please, Note this is Fullcalendar version 5.9.0

Comment: Date formatting has nothing to do with fullCalendar specifically. Nor does this really have anything to do with PHP or Ajax. I've adjusted your tags. Anyway you seem to have found the way to format the time...why not just do the same with the date? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#instance_methods

Comment: Alternatively you could of course use some JS date library that provides nicer formatting methods than the native Date object.

Comment: @ADyson I changed this line as `var start = arg.event.start.getUTCFullYear()+'-'+arg.event.start.getUTCDate()+'-'+arg.event.start.getUTCDay()+' '+arg.event.start.getHours()+':'+arg.event.start.getMinutes()+':'+arg.event.start.getSeconds();` resulted to  `start: 2021-4-1+17:10:0` which gives wrong  date and month, the month was october (10) and the date was 04

Comment: Also i tried to use moment.js to get my desired format it throw an ` a is  undefined function error`  look `var start = moment(arg.event.start).format(''YYYY-MM-DD H:m:s);`

Comment: `getUTCDate()` returns the day of the month, not the month itself, and `getUTCDay()` returns the date of the week, not the day of the month. This is clearly documented in the link I provided. Look again for the function to return the month (clue: it has "month" in the title!!) Also, don't mix UTC and non-UTC, could give strange results depending on your timezone.

Comment: As for `var start = moment(arg.event.start).format(''YYYY-MM-DD H:m:s);`, it contains an obvious typo with the quote marks. If we correct that, then it works fine - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/mdwYWVZ

Comment: @ADyson The above comment with moment gives date with plus sign  `start: "2021-10-04+17:10:0"` I want this  `start: "2021-10-04 17:10:0" , is there a way to replace the + sign with  "" in javascript

Comment: `The above comment with moment gives date with plus sign`...no, it doesn't. Run my demo and look at the console. I'd _guess_ that the space gets replaced with + somehow during the AJAX request due to a URL-encoding/decoding issue but it's unclear where exactly you're seeing that version of the output, or what has happened to the data beforehand.

Comment: But yes of course you can replace a + with a space or whatever else you want...google "replace character in string javascript" and there is no shortage of information. However I suggest fixing the problem at its source rather than sticking a plaster over it at the end.